# Deploy/Manage Rails app to Ec2 with DB on RDS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, web, amazon-ec2

I have some questions related to deploying a rails app to EC2. 
I want to deploy a new Rails app to an EC2 server. I have found ways where we ssh into the ec2 host and deploy the app and leave the server running after ssh dies.

1) Is this the best way to do so? Or should I be using something like Capistrano?

2) I want to setup the DB for my app in AWS RDS. Can anyone help how to do this? Will just providing the hostname in  the database.yml file do it?

3) Lastly, for incrementally making changes to the code, while the server is up, do we just login to the ec2 and pull our changes from say bit-bucket and start the server again or there is some alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Capistrano or any other automated deployment would be the best option instead of deploying manually.

2) Read the documentation about setting up AWS RDS. Its pretty straight forward. And then setup proper security group so that app server can access RDS. Then change the database.yml to reflect RDS server details.

3) Whichever automated deployment you select in step1 should be able to help with the deployments for updates.